# How to properly align checkbox and labels in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two rows of checkboxes and labels.Although horizontal alignment is not an issue , however there is a problem of vertical alignment of second column.How can I achieve a symmetry in this case?

```
<div class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptionsWeek" id="Checkbox0" value="0">Sunday</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptionsWeek" id="Checkbox1" value="1">Monday</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptionsWeek" id="Checkbox2" value="2">Tuesday</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptionsWeek" id="Checkbox3" value="3">Wednesday</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptionsWeek" id="Checkbox4" value="4">Thursday</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptionsWeek" id="Checkbox5" value="5">Friday</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptionsWeek" id="Checkbox6" value="6">Saturday</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwkkf7ts/)

As you can see the alignment of Moday and Friday (checkbox and label) is not proper.

Comment: What's wrong with it? Looks fine from here!

Comment: Monday and Friday checkbox don't align vertically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[I've updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwkkf7ts/7/) with a fixed width on the wrapping div `.col-md-4` and positioned the labels using float with the width of each label set to take 1/3 of the parents width using the `calc` function:

```
label{
    float: left; 
    width: calc(100%/3)
}
```

Comment: Good solution! But is that responsive? :) Depends on OP's requirement.

Comment: it is now, I just updated the parents width to 100% instead of a pixel width :)

Answer (score 4):

What if you wrap each checkbox with a col-sm-3 box?

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptionsWeek" id="Checkbox3" value="3">Wednesday</label>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hobs766o/1/

Comment: I want to keep the layout same actually...ie 4 checkbox on one row and 3 in second row.

Comment: So can't you do it as shown in the fiddle? Since a row can accommodate four "col-sm-3" divs, you can do it?

Comment: What I showed is actually doing that using the bootstrap's predfined styles rather making your own. But if you want, you can define a fixed width to the checkbox container, so all of them will have even width. and I guess, a small fixed width will not harm your responsiveness.

Answer (score 2):

[JsFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vwkkf7ts/6/)

```css
.col-md-4.first label {
    display: block;
    width: 99px;
    float: left;
}
.col-md-4.second label {
    display: block;
    width: 99px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4 first">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptionsWeek" id="Checkbox0" value="0">Sunday</label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptionsWeek" id="Checkbox1" value="1">Monday</label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptionsWeek" id="Checkbox2" value="2">Tuesday</label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptionsWeek" id="Checkbox3" value="3">Wednesday</label>
        </div>

<div style="clear:left"></div>

        <div class="col-md-4 second" style="
">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptionsWeek" id="Checkbox4" value="4">Thursday</label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptionsWeek" id="Checkbox5" value="5">Friday</label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptionsWeek" id="Checkbox6" value="6">Saturday</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```